# JavaScript Form Redirect Based on 2 Variables

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

We would like to use 3 different thank you pages based upon the radio buttons that people select for number of cars and trucks. The current script we use below was created for only cars and works great.

```js
<script>
$("input[name='cars']:checked").live('change', function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case '7 or less':
        window.module.lp.form.data.url = "URL1";
        break;
    case '8 or more':
        window.module.lp.form.data.url = "URL2";
        break;
    }
});
</script>
```

Now we need to add trucks with either “4 or less” or “5 or more” as the options. Here are the possibilities:

Cars: 7 or less & Trucks 4 or less: URL1
Cars: 7 or less & Trucks 5 or more: URL2
Cars: 8 or more: URL3 (same as adding Trucks 4 or less OR Trucks 5 or more)

Does anyone know how to update the existing code to include 2 variables with 3 different thank you pages?

Comment: Which jquery version you are using?

Comment: 1.4.2 is the version we are using.

Answer (score -1):

Is anyone able to further help with this question?